# How to get current order info on the thank you page using shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, woocommerce-theming

I'm trying to introduce a `shortcode` on the `thankyou.php` page to show the details of the order just placed by a customer.

If I write the code in php like this it works and shows the total:
`<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>`

Now I'm trying to get the same result through a shortcode, but I don't know some parameters and therefore can't get it to work.

```
<?php
add_shortcode( 'custom-woocommerce-total' , 'custom_total' );
function custom_total(){
    $customer_id = get_current_user_id();
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id); // I suppose that's not right.
    return $order->get_total();
} ?>
```

can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the whole code function that works? `<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>`

Comment: I literally put it in line 41 after the else (line 40) - https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-thankyou.html

Comment: If you want to insert elements in that exact position you can only do it by overriding the [thankyou.php](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-thankyou.html) template (read the file header). You can find more information [here](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#how-to-edit-files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to get the `order id` first by using `global $wp` variable. Try this:

```php
add_shortcode('custom-woocommerce-total', 'custom_total');

function custom_total($attr)
{
    if (is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')) 
    {
        global $wp;

        $order_id  = absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']);

        if ($order_id) 
        {
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

            if($order)
            {
              return $order->get_total();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And in the `thankyou` page template use it like this:

```php
echo do_shortcode('[custom-woocommerce-total]');
```

Don't forget to override the template.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention, it works correctly. However, I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, perhaps avoiding overwriting the original template.

Comment: Since we're using the shortcode approach, it could **NOT** get any easier than this! FYI, we're **NOT** overwriting the plugin template. We're overriding it. There is a difference between the two. If you don't know about `overriding woocommerce templates`, then please take a moment and [read the documentation](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).